# Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'presentingViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-signin

I am learning the google sign-in to app with GoogleSignIn SDK (Installed with cocoapods). I did not specify version in pod file, its automatically installed GoogleSignIn (4.4.0). Going Through the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift).
According to documentation, To add sign in button we have to write

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self

  // Automatically sign in the user.
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
```

but in latest Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8) i am getting error

```
Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'presentingViewController'
Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'restorePreviousSignIn'
```

I tried to search about the updated version for this but unfortunately not found. Kindly help me out to integrate GoogleSignIn

Comment: Di you `import GoogleSignIn` in your view controller?

Comment: Yes i imported.

Comment: In case we dont import GoogleSignIn then our error will be this 'Use of unresolved identifier 'GIDSignIn''

Comment: Which Xcode version are you uses?

Comment: Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8)

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi which version you may have to use ? GoogleSignIn (5.0.0) !

Comment: In my terminal pod installation history GoogleSignIn (4.4.0). I did not specify version in pod file, its automatically installed GoogleSignIn (4.4.0).

Comment: @SagarBhut pod update worked for me. Thanks for giving me idea.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi always welcome and available for any helps. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136545/ios-android-and-php-dev#

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code is correct if you are using Google Sign-In **v5.0**:

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
```

But since you've installed 4.4.0, you should accept [Vitaly Shpinyov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57806847/4810957).

Or upgrade Google Sign-In to 5.0 or higher by editing your podfile:

```rb
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self

Answer (score 9):

In `viewDidLoad()` of your `ViewController` add the following line:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.uiDelegate = self
```

and make the `ViewController` conform to `GIDSignInUIDelegate` protocol.

Comment: I m getting error, Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'uiDelegate', I am not using cocoapods, and due to certain project dependencies I can not use cocoapods in the project. Can you help me

Comment: It works for me, I tried to download 5.0 version but pods said that it cannot find that. Therefore I have to stick with this way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

In version GoogleSignIn 5.0 you can do the following

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```